# How to replace any_string@a.net to any_string@b.com

Tags: regex

How to replace any_string@a.net to any_string@b.com using RegEx?

I want to strip the @a.net and replace it with @b.com

I've tried

```
(.*@a.net)
```

but the $1 is showing all the string.
So when i try to replace it, it became

```
any_string@a.net@b.com
```

And can someone point me to a nice tutorial regarding RegEx?

Comment: @hwnd what do you mean? I'm completely cluesless

Comment: sorry @hwnd i've edit my question, what i mean is the first matched string is stay the same as previous, but the second (a.net ) change to (b.com)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  We'd love to help you.  You might want to review [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and rethink your posting.

Comment: i've clarify my question. i'm still in the dark for this Regex matter.
if someone can point me to the light. please.

Comment: Also make sure you add the platform you're using -- there are important differences in how regular expressions are interpreted in different libraries and/or languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `()` indicates the capture group. Put the parts of the expression you don't want to capture outside the parenthesis:

```
(.*)@a.net
```

A great site to play around with regular expressions is http://refiddle.co/.

I [fiddled this problem](http://refiddle.co/refiddles/55e3db2975622d20a5010000) already.

Comment: Thanks @PaulProgrammer, that's what i'm looking for.
I'm using this regex match pattern for search rule in cisco exp-e.
I feel like this answer will work.

But how the Narendra answer is producing the same result?

Comment: TMTOWTDI - "There's more than one way to do it"

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
\b@[a-zA-Z].net\b
```

- `\b` to set word boundaries before `@`
- `@` matches the character `@` literally
- `a-z` a single character in the range between `a` and `z` (case sensitive)
- `A-Z` a single character in the range between `A` and `Z` (case sensitive)
- `.` matches any character (except newline)
- `net` matches the characters `net` literally (case sensitive)
- `\b` word boundary

The above regex will capture the given characters literally which you can replace using `@b.com`

And of you simply want to capture only `@a.net` than you can simply use

```
\b@a.net\b
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cY8yF8/1)